# Share processor time between computers

Tags: windows, memory, time, central-processing-unit

I'm a developer and I use lots of applications gadgets. (I WORK ON WINDOWS)
I have two computers (HP Dual Core (3.2Ghz) one with 512Mb and one with 1Gb RAM). So I work on both, but when I work I work only on one!

So here I'm not getting benefit from the second :( and I really want to because I use lot of applications and i need lot of processor time and RAM Memory.

- So is there any application that can "get" processor time and RAM from other computer (sure they are networked)

I consider that solution almost impossible although I have no idea, but I got another idea

- a program that runs the application on computer 1 and let me see (their windows) on computer 2; I already did experiment with Windows Remote Desktop but I need to jump from a desk to another which is not good. I prefer to keep on the same desk.

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: it's 2009, you should have at least 2 GB on both of your machines

Comment: Are you after a windows or linux solution?

Comment: huh forgot it, added it now, windows solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone said, with that kind of processor - you really want to add 2-8 GB of memory to both machines - especially as memory is rather cheap right now. If it's laptops there should be room for at least 2 GB - and sometimes 4 or 8 GB (some Dell XPSs can do this for instance).

As others have said, Synergy will let you use them both from a single keyboard and mouse - almost like you had a single computer with dual monitors (though not completely of course).

The network has way too much latency (and bandwidth) for anything useful except for very specialized batchable tasks like compiling or rendering heavy work that doesn't depend on too much data to be transferred.

You could do stuff like run Incredibuild or whatever distributed build environment your developing platform supports - though the limited amount of memory and the fact that it's only two machines will not give you too much gain.

I'd perhaps set one machine up as a continuous build machine that will keep a working build at all times each time you do commits.

Answer (score 2):

For compilation there is a program called "distcc" which allows you to use time on another computer to speed up compiles.

Some other applications support distribution, like renderers.

Generally it's not worth it as the latency and bandwidth limits of communication between two computers are large. It only makes sense for tasks where the "problem description" and results are small.

Comment: Does distcc work on windows?  He didn't specify windows, but did mention Windows Remote Desktop, so I think he needs a windows solution.

Answer (score 0):

> a program that runs the application on computer 1 and let me see (their windows) on computer 2

[Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) lets you share your keyboard and mouse between to computers.  Good for two computers with two monitors, just move your mouse from one monitor to the other, click on a window and start typing.

> So is there any application that can "get" processor time and RAM from other computer (sure they are networked)

Rewrite everything in Erlang ;-)

Comment: "Rewrite everything in Erlang ;-)"

I think I'll buy a monster PC and save 'headaches'

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably remote desktop.  Remote desktop to the other computer, and you can display its desktop in a window on the local computer.  Then you can run programs on the other computer.

There's no way to seamlessly use the other computer's CPU and RAM as if it was an extension of the local computer.  The cheapest way to fake that is to go out and buy more RAM for the local computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can share a Ramdisk, this way you can get access to fast memory all on one computer. I don't know if this will help you though - maybe compiles running from source on the ramdisk would be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) (if you have a second monitor) to use both computers side-by-side. It may not be exactly what you're looking for, but it is better than nothing (and requires almost no configuration :)